# Record my daily internet usage?

Tags: wireless, 16.04, xubuntu, internet, interface

I want to record my daily internet usage. **NetWorx** alternative for ubuntu software. Networx screenshot take from windows[image: Windows]

Comment: I'm going to agree with the possible duplicate, but you could also look into routers that support DD-WRT that have built in capabilities of tracking your whole network WAN usage.